# Show BinaryStream from Java Servlet in img in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple ajax call in my javascript file which looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "getImage",
    contentType :"application/json",
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    cache : false,
    success : function(data) {

        $.each(data,function(index,item){

            var data = btoa(item._bild);

            $('#bilder').append('<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + data +'" />');
    });                                           
    }                           
});
```

In my Backend Servlet i build a JSON Object with Data and put them into an JSONArray.
That JSONArray i got in my Javascript success call and in this JSONObject there is store the image from my postgresql database.
**Now how can i show that image in my frontend. Because for now i got a broken image icon instead of my real image**:

[image]

My html where i apapend my images :

```
<div id="bilder">
</div>
```

And my JSON file looks like this:

[image]

And my convert

```
case -2:                                
  byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes(column_name);
  obj.put(column_name, DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes));
break;
```

Comment: Please can we see the HTML source for element you're appending the image to?

Comment: May you show an example of your JSON?

Comment: @skilleknarf  have edit my post

Comment: I've checked that this image doesn't render:
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, amF2YS5pby5CeXRlQXJyYXlJbnB1dFN0cmVhbUAzODc5YjM4MQ==" />

Comment: Is the image format definitely jpg and please can you post the code for when you convert the image to base64?